# How can I handle triggers in FastAPI, SQLAlchemy, and SQL Server when inserting data into a table?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, triggers, fastapi

I already have tables and triggers created in database,
now when I try to create a new record in the database it gives error.
But if I delete trigger  then  I can add new records in database,

Here is the error

> {
> "detail": "internal server error while creating organization (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The target table 'organization' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause. (334) (SQLExecDirectW)")\n[SQL: INSERT INTO organization (name, code, organization_administrator, customer_company, city, state, country, create_date, create_user, update_date, update_user, active, comments) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]\n[parameters: ('Eric Item Set-1', 'EricTest-64-1', None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 3, 21, 2, 43, 352446), None, None, None, None, None)]\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)"
> }

here is my code

---

model.py

```
class Organization(Base):
    __tablename__ = "organization"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    code = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    organization_administrator = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    customer_company = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    city = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    state = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    country = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    create_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    create_user = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    update_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    update_user = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    active = Column(Boolean, nullable=True)
    comments = Column(String, nullable=True)
    _table_args_ = {'implicit_returning':False}
```

---

schema.py

```
from typing import Optional ,List
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime


class MyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    class Config():
        from_attributes = True


class OrganizationBase(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    code: Optional[str] = None
    organization_administrator: Optional[int] = None
    customer_company: Optional[str] = None
    city: Optional[str] = None
    state: Optional[str] = None
    country: Optional[str] = None
    create_date: Optional[datetime] = None
    create_user: Optional[int] = None
    update_date: Optional[datetime] = None
    update_user: Optional[int] = None
    active: Optional[bool] = None
    comments: Optional[str] = None


class OrganizationCreate(OrganizationBase):
    name: str
    code: str


class OrganizationUpdate(OrganizationBase):
    pass


class OrganizationInDBBase(OrganizationBase):
    id: int

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True


class Organization(OrganizationInDBBase):
    pass


class Pagination(BaseModel):
    total_records: int
    current_page: int
    total_pages: int


class OrganizationWithPagination(BaseModel):
    data : List[Organization]
    pagination : Pagination
```

---

endpoint.py

```
@router.post('', response_model=OrganizationSchema)
def create(request: OrganizationCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return services.create(request, db)
```

---

service.py

```
def create(request: OrganizationCreate, db: Session):
    try:
        request.create_date = datetime.now()
        request.update_date = None
        instance = Organization(**dict(request))
        db.add(instance)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(instance)
        return instance
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=400, detail=f"internal server error while creating organization {e}")
```

I have tried to insert record using raw query, and able to insert.
But what if I don’t want to use raw query?
And also if I am using raw query then I am unable to return newly created record id.

Note: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Try using `__table_args__` instead of `_table_args_`

Comment: It looks like your ORM returns the id of the new record to itself in order to update the model (which is fairly common behaviour). Having a trigger breaks its ability to do that which is why its unhappy.

Comment: it works for this table but for another tables now it is giving this error,

File "/Volumes/workspace/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/pyodbc.py", line 601, in post_exec
    self._lastrowid = int(row[0])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'